# Rename bulk directories but keeping a part of the original directory name linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a few directories with names like:

```
test_1
test_23
test_4
test_19
test_15
```

And I wish to rename them

```
test_name_1
test_name_23
test_name_4
test_name_19
test_name_15
```

So just adding `name_` in the directory name, but keeping the same number on the end.

I thought the `rename` command might work, but don't know how to keep a part of the original name the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish it with `rename` as you supposed:

```
rename test_ test_name_ test_[0-9]*
```

The `test_` part is the pattern to find; `test_name_` is the replacement; `test_[0-9]*` filters the files you want to rename.

Comment: Thanks, I found that "rename 's/test_/test_name_/' test_[0-9]*" works well

Comment: ^^ I was about to comment the same. Some variants of rename accept only the [basic syntax](http://man.cx/rename), whereas some accept [perl expression](http://man.cx/prename), though the command name is just `rename`.